# Display SKUs in admin order list for new HPOS

Tags: wp-admin, order

I used to have code to display column with order SKUs in admin order list page. After introducing WooCommerce HPOS I changed the hooks accordingly (because of admin list page change) but it looks like there is a new global order object now. This is what I have - it does not work:

```
add_filter('manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_columns', 'order_items_column' );
function order_items_column( $order_columns )
{
    $order_columns['order_products'] = 'Produkty';
    return $order_columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_custom_column' , 'order_items_column_cnt' );
function order_items_column_cnt( $colname )
{
    global $the_order; // the global order object
    if ( $colname == 'order_products' ) {
        // get items from the order global object
        $order_items = $the_order->get_items();
        if ( !is_wp_error( $order_items ) ) {
            foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ) {
                $product = $order_item->get_product();
                // product checking
                if ( is_object($product ) ) {
                    $sku =  $product->get_sku()  ;
                    echo $order_item['quantity'] .'×' . $sku . ' ';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo $order_item['quantity'];
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_items() on null
I could not find in HPOS reference to the new global order object. Any idea how to replace it?